# Is javascript itself synchronous and it's the environment that is asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Native javascript is single threaded and synchronous. Only a few objects can run asynchronously and get added to the callback queue such as HTTP requests, timers and events. These asynchronous objects are a result of the actual javascript environment and not javascript itself. setTimeout() seems to be the go to for examples for asynchronous code. That function gets moved to the web API container and then eventually the callback queue. There doesn't seem to be a way to write asynchronous code in javascript that doesn't involve using objects that get moved to the Web API container. I can write my own custom objects with callbacks, but the most that will do is structure it to run in the proper order. You can never write javascript code that runs in parallel that doesn't rely on those objects.

This is my understanding of how it works, if I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: More or less, this is so. Ask more specific questions to get more specific answers.

Comment: JavaScript is synchronous. async stuff is just a state of mind, as JavaScript can only run one thing at a time. In JavaScript async just means that something will run and/or finish at a later date but still in a synchronous way.

Comment: nodejs however, has introduced [Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) which is still experimental though.

Comment: I am aware of node.js and how it uses C to create more threads for some procedures.

Comment: @getOffMyLawn Browsers do have WebWorkers since years, which are basically exactly the same.

Comment: Are you sure? The doc says `The worker_threads module enables the use of threads that execute JavaScript in parallel`. A worker is a new process with its own event queue. I don't think a thread has its own event queue... I could be wrong though...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn it absolutely does. An event is not necessarily "mouse clicked". For worker threads the event is typically just "received message, with data" when communicating with the main process. Then that thread is free to schedule timeouts, call async services, and handle responses, all via the event queue.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` are just a convenient way to trigger some asynchronous behavior for an example. It is part of standard javascript library in all implementations, and not just part of the browser environment.

But all other sources of async code depend on some external process. When making an HTTP request, your javascript thread tells the browser to make a request (what headers, what url, etc). The browser, according to its own compiled internals, then formats the request, sends it, waits for a response, and eventually adds an item to javascript's event loop to be processed next time the event loop runs. File system access and database queries are two other common examples of async code that depends on external processes (the OS, and a database, respectively)

How javascript handles async code in a single threaded process is all down to this [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). This event loop in psuedo code is basically this:

```
while (queue.waitForMessage()) {
  queue.processNextMessage();
}
```

`setTimeout` tells the environment to pop something into that queue at some point of the future. But the processing of that queue is single threaded. Only one event message can be handled at the same time, but any number can be added to that queue.

---

You can get true concurrency with [workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), but this basically adds a new javascript process that is itself single threaded, and has a method of communicating with messages to and from the main javascript process.

Comment: " But all other sources of async code depend on some external process " Wrong. Promises.

Comment: How do promises invalidate this explanation? A promise is simply a nice API around managing handlers of messages from the event queue.

Comment: No, not quite. `Promise.resolve("try it").then(console.log); console.log("it works")` They also guarantee asynchronous resolution, they are the only way to create asynchrony defined in the ES spec (and workers).

Comment: @JonasWilms which is functionally identical to `setTimeout(() => console.log("try it"), 0); console.log("it works")`. I believe `Promise.resolve` simply doesn't execute immediately, but instead schedules something for the next run loop.

Comment: Yes, kind of. ... But Promises are core js, `setTimeout` isn't (but its a de facto standard though)

Comment: `setTimeout(..., 0)` doesn't execute immediately either. **If this parameter is omitted, a value of 0 is used, meaning execute "immediately", or more accurately, as soon as possible. Note that in either case, the actual delay may be longer than intended;**

Comment: "as soon as possible" as in "after the current event loop ends, and next event loop is allowed to begin"